# I need to acces second time to tcp server in Python

Tags: python-2.7

This is my server code. I need to connect 2 times but it must same time.
Maybe my thread is wrong. I don't know but I need help.

```
import threading
import socket
import random


soket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
num=random.choice(range(101))

host="0.0.0.0"
port=7972

soket.bind((host,port))
print ("%s : %d server balşatıldı" % (host,port))  
soket.listen(5)
print "kullanıcı bekleniyor"
conn,adres=soket.accept()
print "Bağlantı kuruldu."
def dinle():

    print num

    data=conn.recv(1024)
    print data
    conn.sendall("hoşgeldiniz\nBir sayı tuuttum bakalım bulabilecekmisin?" )
    while True:

        tahmin=int(conn.recv(1024))
        if tahmin==num:
            conn.sendall("tebrikler")
            break

        else:
            conn.sendall("bulamadın")

for i in range(10):
    t1=threading.Thread(target=dinle)
    t1.start()
    t1.join()
    soket.close()
```

This is easy number guessing game.
Anybody can solve it please.

Comment: Have you looked at using `SocketServer` https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html?

Comment: Yes I look but I can't understand anything.